# How to determine USB Host device type?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to read the contents of a USB mass storage flash drive using [this guide at android.developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html). I am having a problem deciding which drive is actually the flash drive.

I am using this code to iterate through the devices:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        usbManager = (UsbManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
        monitorUsb();
    }

    private async void monitorUsb()
    {
        var deviceList = usbManager.DeviceList;
        foreach (var device in deviceList.Values)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("USB",device.DeviceName);
            Debug.WriteLine("USB",device.DeviceProtocol.ToString());
        }
        await Task.Delay(30000);
        monitorUsb();
    }
```

I have two devices plugged in, a mouse and a flash drive.

The above code produces the following:

```
[0:] /dev/bus/usb/003/003
[0:] 0
[0:] /dev/bus/usb/003/019
[0:] 0
[0:] /dev/bus/usb/003/020
[0:] 0
```

By a process of elimination, `020` is the flash drive, and `019` is the mouse. I don't know what `003` is, perhaps something internal or one of the other ports (I have `adb` connected through onboard ethernet).

According to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbConstants.html#USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE), the protocol of `USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE` is `8` and `0` relates to `USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE`

How can I decide in code which of the devices is the flash drive if they both return `USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE`? I have looked at the other properties of `UsbDevice` and none seem to return anything useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking the the wrong protocol.

```
        foreach (var device in deviceList.Values)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < device.InterfaceCount; i++)
            {
                var deviceInterface = device.GetInterface(i) as UsbInterface;
                Debug.WriteLine("USB", deviceInterface.InterfaceProtocol.ToString());
            };

            //Debug.WriteLine("USB", device.DeviceName);
            //Debug.WriteLine("USB", device.DeviceProtocol.ToString());
        }
```

This returns the protocol as `80` rather than `8` as the documents suggest. I cannot explain this.

Comment: Use deviceInterface.getInterfaceClass().

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have been working on this continually since 2016. I can finally rest.